# Unsuccessful fread() of int stored in binary file, segmentation fault

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fread

There seem to be of the order of 10 questions and (mostly) successful answers solving segmentation faults cause by misused fread()'s in C. That being said, I am having such a problem but have not found a solution.

I have a binary file containing an `int` (call it **nbins**) and an array of `float`s (of size **nbins**). When I try to read this file, it successfully opens and points to the file handle, but then gives a segmentation fault error when reading the **nbins** `int`. Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BPATH "/path/to/file"

int main(int agrc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fd;
    int num;
    char fname[500]={};

    int nbins;
    float *coords;

    num = 5;
    sprintf(fname,"%s/file%d.dat", BPATH, num);

    if(!(fd=fopen(fname,"rb")))
    {
        printf("Can't open file: %s\n\n",fname);
        exit(0);
    }    

    printf("Reading input file:\n");
    printf("%p: %s\n", fd, fname);       // prints successfully

    fread(&nbins, sizeof(int), 1, fd);   
    printf("nbins = %d", nbins);         // seg faults before this print

    /* EDIT: the above print isn't properly flushed without an \n    
     * The seg fault was not caused by the fread(), but the lack of  
     * the above print lead to the confusion                         */

    coords = malloc(nbins * sizeof(float));
    fread(coords, sizeof(float), nbins, fd);

    fclose(fd);
    free(coords);

    return(0);
}
```

The file was created with the following formatting:

```
int nbins[1];
nbins[0] = 5;                          // this 5 is just an example...
fwrite(nbins, sizeof(int), 1, file_ptr);
fwrite(coords, sizeof(float), nbins[0], file_ptr);
```

I have also tried using:

```
int *nbins = malloc(sizeof(int));
fread(nbins, sizeof(int), 1, fd);
```

but this did not solve the problem.
The file does exist and is readable; I can read it just fine using Python, with NumPy's `fromfile()`. Am I missing something obvious? Thanks!

Comment: Read documentation of [fread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread). Test its result (using `perror` on failure). Compile with all warnings and debug info `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. **Use the debugger** `gdb` & `vagrind`.

Comment: Can you really reproduce the error with the *exact* code you have presented in the question?  If so, how are you certain that the segfault occurs where you say it does?  I would find that behavior very surprising, but I can think of some variations that would be less surprising.

Comment: I don't think the segfault is where you think it is.

Comment: Let me amend the comment `seg faults here`. See new text!

Comment: Now you should check the result of `fread` as suggested.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong in your code. But your example is not complete, the declaration of `fname` is missing and depending on how `fname` is declared you could get various problems.

Comment: You do not have \n in the printf after fread - so maybe you just do not see it?

Comment: It would be better to initialize `nbins` to 0.

Comment: What is `fname`?  Please provide a *complete* example.

Comment: ^ditto + the input file.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry I missed the declaration of `fname` in the minimal example. Should be complete, I will check if it does compile now

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky yes, well spotted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), with the following scenario:

- `int nbins;` does not initialize `nbins`, so it contains junk data, potentially a very large number.
- `fread(&nbins, sizeof(int), 1, fd);` is not tested so could fail and keep `nbins` uninitialized. Read about [fread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread).
- `printf("nbins = %d", nbins);` has no `\n` and is not followed by an explicit `fflush` so don't show anything (since `stdout` is *usually* line-buffered).
- `coords = malloc(nbins * sizeof(float));` would request a huge amount of memory, so would fail and get `NULL` in `coords`
- `fread(coords, sizeof(float), nbins, fd);` writes to the `NULL` pointer, giving a segmentation violation, since UB

You are very lucky. Things could be [worse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) (we all could be annihilated by a black hole). You could also experiment some [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html), or even worse, have some execution which *seems* to apparently work.

Next time, **please avoid *UB***. I don't want to disappear in a black hole, so bear with us.

BTW, if you use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with all warnings and debug info : `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. It would have warned you. And if it did not, you'll get the SEGV under the `gdb` debugger. On Linux both [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and [strace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) could have helped too.

Notice that useless initialization (e.g. an *explicit* `int nbins = 0;` in your case) don't harm in practice. The optimizing compiler is likely to remove them if they are useless (and when they are not useless, as in your case, they are very fast).

### Mandatory read

Lattner's blog: [*What Every C Programmer should know about UB*](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html). Related notion: the [As-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule).

Read also the documentation of *every* function you are using (even as common  as `printf`).

Comment: The lack of `\n` in the `nbins` print was relevant indeed. `nbins` is read in correctly, so the segmentation fault is occurring later. Thanks for your help!

Comment: As my question has been shown to be incorrect in it's assertions, I will accept this as the correct answer (since it pointed out what was wrong with the question). The actual error causing the seg fault doesn't relate to the `fread()` of the `int`

Comment: But seriously, work hard to avoid UB. I don't want to disappear in a black hole.