# Data stored in text file using fwrite is unreadable in C

Tags: c, file, file-io, fwrite

When data is stored on a text file using fwrite, like this, where t is a struct:

```
fwrite(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fptr);
```

The output in the text file ends up as:

```
楷獬湯찀쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌敷敷
```

(Above is a sample, not the full output)

Why does this happen?

Edit: t is a struct - where user is prompted for two strings, username and password. Here's a basic template - it was a friend who had the problem and I don't have the actual code snippet with me to share, but I assume it was something equivalent to this. I know it's not very helpful, sorry about that. Any help is appreciated.

```
struct details {
char username[32], password[32];
}

int main() {
struct details t;
scanf("%s",t.username);
scanf("%s",t.password);
}
```

File is opened as a+ mode.

Edit2: Ran friend's code, initialized struct with new file, inputting username and password as '0'. Here's the hexdump.

```
file name: admins.txt
mime type: 

0000-0010:  30 00 cc cc-cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc  0....... ........
0000-0020:  cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc  ........ ........
0000-0030:  cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc  ........ ........
0000-0040:  cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc  ........ ........
0000-0050:  cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc  ........ ........
0000-0060:  30 00 cc cc-cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc  0....... ........
0000-0070:  cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc  ........ ........
0000-0080:  cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc  ........ ........
0000-0090:  cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc  ........ ........
0000-00a0:  cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc-cc cc cc cc  ........ ........
```

Comment: You are not writing a text file. You are writing a binary file. BTW what is `t`?

Comment: You probably have written some "non-text" symbols. If you try to interpret with a text editor such "non-text" symbols it will just display garbage. Try to open with a hex editor and you will see the data written in the file is correct, it's just text editors can't understand it, because they can understand only text.

Comment: This can not be answered unless you provide some more information on the data being written, the type of file, etc

Comment: open the file with vim and then use (ESC) :%!xxd (ENTER) to display hex values. Also as suggested provide a bit more info...

Comment: I posted the question while I was at uni, just got home. Anyhow will clarify now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read documentation of [fwrite](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite). It is for [*binary*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file) IO. But you have a textual format.

You could consider [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) your [textual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_protocol) file. Learn about [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), [sscanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), etc...

Consider also using existing textual formats like [JSON](http://json.org/), [YAML](http://yaml.org/), etc... You'll find many libraries for them (e.g. [jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) in C).

Since you are interested in (or are observing) Chinese characters, read [Utf8 Everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/).

Also, compile your code [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and learn how to [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand the behaviour of your program. You might use [watchpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html) to understand when a location is written.

Read much more about [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46526702/841108) of it (junk file content is a possible effect of UB, but it could be much worse).

Comment: Thanks, but simply out of curiosity's sake, why exactly is it that it ends up displaying these strange mandarin-ish characters?

Comment: @Terrornado Because you're interpreting a binary file as text.

Answer (score 0):

Is user entered input a Unicode string? Initialize struct to all zeros. Paste hexdump of the file.

Comment: This is the result:
`0쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌0쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌쳌`

Hexdump is too long, in main now

Comment: you can send initial few bytes hexdump of the file using `hexdump -c <file>`

Comment: sorry, on windows, I assume that would be for unix?