# What is this value?

Tags: c

```
printf("%d", "10+10");
```

then I get "17661648" and similar thing in too

```
printf("%d", "Hello");
```

What is this value?
sum of `"1,0,+,1,0"` `"H,e,l,l,o"` as ASCII code in decimal number? or just a garbage value?

Comment: Garbage value . You can only supply an `int` value for `%d`, the compiler should warn you.

Comment: Probably the address of the string literal.

Answer (score 8):

According the the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (see its §7.21.6.1) you've got [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (UB), which is also documented [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) or in [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html). So be *very* [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46526702/841108), since arbitrarily bad things could happen. So take the habit of reading the documentation of every function that you are using.

If you ask your compiler to disassemble the generated form of your program (e.g. by compiling with `gcc -S -O -fverbose-asm` if you [use](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) GCC, on Linux/x86-64) you'll discover that the address of the string literal `"10+10"` is passed (on 64 bits) and then truncated (inside `printf`, because of the `%d`) to an `int`. So the 17661648 could correspond to the lowest 32 bits of that address.

Details are of course implementation specific (and could vary from one run to the next one because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), depends upon the compiler and the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and the target system). To actually understand and explain the behavior requires diving into many details (your particular computer, your particular [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) and [optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) flags, your particular [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), the compiler generated assembler & machine code, your particular [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library), etc....) and you don't want to do that (because it could take years).

You should take several hours to read more [about UB](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html). It is an essential notion to understand when programming in C, and you should avoid it.

Any good compiler would have warned you, and then you should improve your code to get no warnings. If using GCC, be sure to compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to get all warnings and debug info. Then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand the actual behavior of your program on your system. In all cases, be sure to configure your C compiler to enable all warnings and debug info, and learn to use your debugger. Read [*How To Debug Small Programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I'm a beginner of C and know not much about it. That's why I couldn't understand all of your comment but I think it is really helpful to me. Thank you for giving me a guide to study, I would try to as you tell.

Comment: You absolutely need to read more about UB. It is an essential concept in C programming, important even to beginners. And you should take the habit of compiling with all warnings and debug info. So read the documentation of your compiler and of your debugger.

Comment: And any warning should be understood as an *error*.

Answer (score -1):

Someting like this should work:

```
printf("Hello");
total = 20;
printf("10+10 = %d", total);
```