# How does free function on pointer in C work?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

Have a look at this C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int *ptr_one;

    ptr_one = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));

    if (ptr_one == 0){
        printf("ERROR: Out of memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    *ptr_one = 25;
    printf("%d\n", *ptr_one);

    free(ptr_one);
    printf("%d\n", *ptr_one);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, it gives this output:

```
25
25
```

Even after I free the pointer, why is it still giving 25 as output?

Comment: @KeineLust: not memory leak, but undefined behavior.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, you are right, totally misreaded the question

Comment: Because it's very unlikely that bunch of memory has been re-allocated and overwritten within the short time your 2 lines run, and you were lucky the OS didn't flag your process. Anyway that's UB as you are not supposed to access freed memory (which doesn't belong to your process anymore).

Comment: So many exact duplicates it hurts...

Comment: @RingØ: `free`-d memory can still belong to your process (e.g. to its virtual address space), but you should not use it. See my answer for an explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read a lot more about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (UB). Your code has some (you are not allowed to do something with a pointer after it has been `free`-d).

> Even after I free the pointer, why is it still giving 25 as output?

It is UB. You have bad luck. Be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46526702/841108).

Read the C11 standard specification [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

You don't really need to understand how `free` works (but you need to understand how you should use it). However, it usually uses some [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) dealing with [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). On [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), many [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) implementations -e.g. GNU [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) - are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (so you can download and study their source code), and their `malloc`  might *sometimes* get more virtual address space with system calls like [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (or the old [sbrk(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html)), and their `free` might *sometimes* release some space with [munmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/munmap.2.html).

What usually happens is that [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) works differently for "large" and "small" memory zones. For small zones, the C library prefer to re-use previously `free`-d ones in future `malloc`-s. It gets (sometimes) from the OS a large chunk of memory (using `mmap`) and split that chunk into pieces. When you `free` a small zone, that zone is simply added to some collection of pieces, for future `malloc`. So it still "exists" but using it is UB (and that explains the behavior your are observing).

The [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) utility is a very useful tool to hunt memory related UB.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that happens when you use `free` is that you tell the operating system (or similar) that you promise that will not use the pointer again. The function `free` takes a pointer as argument, not a pointer to pointer, and can thus not change the pointer.

Comment: Then what does it do? What is use of writing free function there?

Comment: You tell the operating system that you are done with the memory chunk, so the OS may use it for something else.