# "free(): invalid pointer" error while freeing allocated memory of a hash table

Tags: c

Edit:

I already ran my program through valgrind which pointed to the two functions I've included here:

```
==6768== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==6768==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6768==    by 0x42187C: free_memory (test4.c:232)
==6768==    by 0x42087E: main (test4.c:93)
==6768==  Address 0x10855f8 is 0 bytes inside data symbol "hash_table"
==6768== 
==6768== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==6768==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6768==    by 0x421856: free_memory (test4.c:224)
==6768==    by 0x42087E: main (test4.c:93)
==6768==  Address 0x1085708 is 272 bytes inside data symbol "hash_table"
==6768== 
==6768== 
==6768== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6768==     in use at exit: 36,504 bytes in 676 blocks
==6768==   total heap usage: 679 allocs, 679 frees, 36,666 bytes allocated
==6768== 
==6768== 36,504 bytes in 676 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==6768==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6768==    by 0x4208C9: init_table (test4.c:105)
==6768==    by 0x42073D: main (test4.c:44)
==6768== 
==6768== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6768==    definitely lost: 36,504 bytes in 676 blocks
==6768==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6768==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6768==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6768==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6768== 
==6768== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6768== ERROR SUMMARY: 677 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

---

Good day everyone. I have an interesting problem if you have some time. I keep running into an error with `free()` function from `stdlib.h` for days. My code is somewhat large, so I tested it to get the same error in a minified version. I know where the problem occurs but I can't formulate a solution for it. All help is much appreciated. Full error text:

```
*** Error in `./sample': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001084078 ***
Aborted
```

The code includes a data structure to index words with their first and second letters' alphabetical indexes as key values, and stores the word itself in a linked list pointed by a node-head living in the corresponding indexed location. It's a very simple idea. As a great man once said; talk is cheap, show me code. Start reading the data structure definitions from (1) to (3), it will make more sense:

```
#include <stdlib.h>


// (3) Node (of a linked list), represents a single word indexed first letter of-
// column[i] and second letter of row[i]. Think of the z axis of a table

typedef struct _node
{
    char *value;
    struct _node *next;
}
node;


// (2) Row, represents the second letter of a word. Think of the y axis of a table

typedef struct _row
{
    node rows[26];
}
row;


// (1) Column, represents the first letter of a word. Think of the x axis of a table

typedef struct _column
{
    row columns[26];
}
column;


// These are detailed below

void init_table(column *table);
void free_memory(column *table);

column hash_table;


int main(void)
{

    init_table(&hash_table);
    free_memory(&hash_table);

    return 0;
}


// Initialize node-heads. If I don't do this, I get a 'runtime error: null-
// pointer passed as argument' when I want to access and store something in 
// "node->next" or "node->value" for the first time

void init_table(column *table)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)  // For each column
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)  // For each row
        {
            // Allocate space for a new node, as the head of a linked list.
            // Max word length will be 45 letters, allocate that much space
            node *first_node = malloc(sizeof(char) * 46 + sizeof(node *));

            // Assign new node with value of "none", and "next" (pointer) of NULL
            *first_node = (node) { .value = "none", .next = NULL };

            // Store this node in the current table cell
            table->columns[i].rows[j] = *first_node;
        }
    }
}


// Free all the memory on the heap, allocated previously
void free_memory(column *table)
{
    node *ptr;  // To guide the "del_node"
    node *del_node;  // To delete guided memory locations
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)  // columns
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)  // rows
        {
            // Address of the first node of the current linked list
            ptr = &table->columns[i].rows[j];

            while(1)
            {
                if(ptr->next)  // If node does not point to "NULL"
                {
                    del_node = ptr;  // Guide the "del_node"
                    ptr = ptr->next;  // Advance "ptr" to the next node
                    free(del_node);  // Free the memory pointed by "del_node"
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Free "ptr" in case there was no next node but "ptr" 
            // was pointing to a node

            if (ptr) free(ptr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `node.value` intented to be used?

Comment: This doen't make much sense: `node *first_node = malloc(sizeof(char) * 46 + sizeof(node *));`  For which purpose do you want to add 46 characters? How would you access them? This also creates a memory leak as you don't store the pointer but only make a copy of the content

Comment: Strange variable names, regarding their types' names.

Comment: A "column" is a an array or 26 "columns" typed "row"?

Comment: The question was "how" not "for what".

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) on your entire program

Comment: Maybe you want to make `value` a `char value[46]` instead of a pointer

Comment: Your analogy is fine but your naming is off by 1 level.

Comment: BTW: For such a tiny program you should start using a debugger to run through your code. At least it will tell you where your error happens.

Comment: You are **extremely** confused about pointers. Everything in your attempt is basically broken. You need to brush up on your linked lists first. Write functions that work on a single linked list. Debug them. Then just have a 26×26 array of linked lists.

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and the documentation of *every* [function and header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/header) that you use.  Compile with all warnings and debug info, so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` [when](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) using GCC. Improve your code to get no warnings. Use the debugger `gdb`  and `valgrind` to understand the behavior of your program. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51692671/841108).

Answer (score 3):

There are tons of problems in that code.

Your error probably comes from this piece:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)  // rows
    {
        // Address of the first node of the current linked list
        ptr = &table->columns[i].rows[j];
```

Remember: The table is a global variable which is not dynamically allocated.
`ptr` points to the array element of this static variable.

```
        while(1)
        {
            if(ptr->next)  // If node does not point to "NULL"
            {
                del_node = ptr;  // Guide the "del_node"
                ptr = ptr->next;  // Advance "ptr" to the next node
                free(del_node);  // Free the memory pointed by "del_node"
            }
```

Here you try to free the node that is in the array. Not a dynamically allocated memory location. That won't fly.

Looking at the way you init your table, we find some more problems:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)  // For each row
    {
        // Allocate space for a new node, as the head of a linked list.
        // Max word length will be 45 letters, allocate that much space
        node *first_node = malloc(sizeof(char) * 46 + sizeof(node *));
```

You have 46 bytes of memory that cannot be accessed using the `node` type.

```
        // Assign new node with value of "none", and "next" (pointer) of NULL
        *first_node = (node) { .value = "none", .next = NULL };
```

While `value` is a pointer to char, this may work. But if you intent to use dynamically allocated memory for other nodes, you need to free it afterwards. This will not work with string literals.

```
        // Store this node in the current table cell
        table->columns[i].rows[j] = *first_node;
```

You copy the content of the allocated memory (of course without the 46 extra bytes) and then you forget about the allocated memory. You are not able to free it any more.

If these node each are the head of a list, you should not allocate memory for them at all as they are static.