# Sleep system call ,What is the default sleep time?

Tags: c, sleep

What is the default sleep time if we don't pass any arguments to sleep( ) function?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int pid,dip,cpid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        printf("\n first child is created %d",getpid());
    }
    else
    {
        dip = fork();
        if (dip == 0)
        {
            printf("\n second process is creatred %d",getpid());
        }
        else
        {
            sleep();
            cpid = wait(0);
            printf("\n child with pid %d  ", cpid);
            cpid = wait(0);
            printf("\n child with pid %d  ",cpid);
            printf("\n I am parent \n");
        }
    }
}
```

What is the output of the above code?

Comment: There is no such thing. Not passing an argument is an error.

Comment: Which `sleep` function exactly? From which library?

Comment: What do you think is the output?

Comment: Try to compile it? Does it compile? If not, then the book is wrong.

Comment: first child is created 4998
 second process is creatred 4999  
This is the output that I am getting

Comment: And then it stops

Comment: I don't think that the `sleep` function would work in the case above as as far as I know there's no `sleep` function defined in `stdio.h`.

Comment: Its compiling and working

Comment: BTW, take the habit to *end* (not start) `printf` format strings with `\n`

Comment: Take the habit to read the documentation of *every* function you are calling.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to enable a good set of warnings.  For GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings` as a minimum (that will help identify the use of `sleep()` without a visible prototype); consider also `-Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` for identifying some other common mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not call a function (including `sleep`) which has not been *declared*. According to the [sleep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) man page, you should `#include <unistd.h>`; on my Linux/Debian system `/usr/include/unistd.h` declares:

```
 extern unsigned int sleep (unsigned int __seconds);
```

If you don't declare a function (this is bad habit; Use `gcc` [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `-Wall -Wmissing-prototypes` to be warned) it has unspecified arguments and `int` result.

If you did (like you should) `#include <unistd.h>` your code won't even compile (the call to `sleep` without arguments would be marked as error).

In practice, your `sleep` call is invoked with whatever garbage value is in the register used to pass the first argument. This is typical [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and you cannot predict that value, and you should be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46526702/841108).

So there is no default sleep time, and stricto sensu your question makes no sense. Check by reading the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) and [the](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/sleep.html) POSIX standards.