# C minimum bytes read

Tags: c

I'm curious why when reading less than 4 bytes from a file, the output is corrupted.

Here is my test file:

```
user@UnixVM:~/labs$ cat foo.txt
helloworld
```

And a simple program to read from the file:

```
int main()
{
        int file=0;
        if((file=open("foo.txt",O_RDONLY)) < -1)
                return 1; 
        char buffer[11];        
        read(file,buffer,3);
        printf("%s\n",buffer);
        return 0;
}
```

The output is corrupted and may be different between executions:

```
user@UnixVM:~/labs$ gcc -Wall lab1_4.c -o lab1_4 ; ./lab1_4
hel2
user@UnixVM:~/labs$ gcc -Wall lab1_4.c -o lab1_4 ; ./lab1_4
hel▒
```

But every time I make number of bytes to read greater or equal to 4 (`read(file,buffer,4);`), it works fine.

Comment: You need to terminate strings (to send to `printf()`) with a `'\0'`. Try `char buffer[11] = "";`

Comment: Cheap fix -- initialize your buffer, e.g. `char buffer[11] = "";` then don't write more than 10 characters. In C, every function that expects a *string* expects that string to be *nul-terminated*. It is up to you to do the accounting on your character arrays you want to use as a string. If the character following the last valid character in the array isn't `'\0'` -- then it's not a string, it's just an array. Also note that functions meant to fill buffers with strings (e.g. like `fgets`, POSIX `getline` -- ensure the resulting buffer is *nul-terminated*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your output is "corrupted" because `buffer` does not contain a <kbd>NUL</kbd> terminated C string. Read more about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46526702/841108) (UB sometimes *appears* to work, and that might explain what you experiment).

So before your call to `read` add `memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer))` to clear your `buffer`. Or initialize it with `char buffer[11] ="";` (both are nearly equivalent and likely, with optimizations enabled e.g. `gcc -O2`, to generate the same machine code). Since your buffer is 11 bytes long and you `read` at most 3 bytes you'll then be sure that it is <kbd>NUL</kbd> terminated after the `read`.

Be sure to compile with all warnings and debug info (so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g lab1_4.c -o lab1_4` in your case). Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Read carefully the documentation of [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and of every function you are using. Notice the return count from `read`. You should test and use it.

Comment: personally I'd be adding the NUL based on the return value of `read`, rather than pre-initialising the entire buffer with `\0` before hand.

Comment: `char buffer[11] = "";` is enough.It ensures initialization of the array. First character is a `'\0'` because is is what initializer contains, and rules for aggregate initialization ensure that all remaining bytes are initialized to 0.

Comment: Yes, that might be a useful optimization. In practice, a system call like `read` is always *much more* costly than a `memset` (unless the buffer is huge).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch why reading more than 4 bytes has no such issues?

Comment: @usingnamespace "luck" - you just happened to hit some memory that already had NUL characters in it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't consider that an optimisation, as such.  It's more a case of "why bother pre-filling" when only a single NUL is required, and then only because the OP wants to use `printf` to display it.   Heck, I've been programming in C for 30+ years but I couldn't be 100% sure that the initialisation via `char buffer[11] = ""` actually guarantees NUL initialisation of the entire buffer.  If I wanted that I'd consider a more explicit `char buffer[11] = { '\0', }`.

Comment: Both are doing the same as a `memset` and are initializing the *entire* buffer with zero bytes.

Comment: if I write a function `size_t foo()  { char buffer[11] = ""; return strlen(buffer); }` and then look at the `clang` assembly output with `-O2` I see the explicit initialisation to NUL, and then the strlen call.   Curiously, if I replace the "" with a non-empty constant the compiler just replaces the code with an explicit return of the length of that constant.    OTOH, `gcc` will recognise either an empty string or a non-empty string constant and return its length directly, but if I use `char buffer[11] = { 65, }`  instead of `char buffer[11] = "A"` it defeats that optimisation.

Comment: Read about the [as-if rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15718279/841108)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch oh, sure, it was just an observation about how the optimisers actually work.  The as-if rule ought to allow clang to `return 0` as GCC does when given an empty string, but yet it doesn't.  Give it a _non-empty_ string initialiser, though, and it does.