# malloc is failing to allocate memory

Tags: c, malloc, defragmentation

I'm writing a C Code to solve Euler equations. My code works perfectly fine on the cluster but not on my pc. Seems to be an issue with malloc(). It is not being able to allocate the requested memory and fails.

How do i make it work? is it something to do with Defragmentation? But the system settings show (0% Defragmented).

Just including a part of malloc() code here.

```
double **u, **rho_u, **rho,    
int Size = 1000;
u = (double**)malloc(Size*sizeof(double*));
for(i=0;i<=Size;i++)
    u[i] = (double*)malloc(Size*sizeof(double));

rho_u = (double**)malloc(Size*sizeof(double*));
for(i=0;i<=Size;i++)
    rho_u[i] = (double*)malloc(Size*sizeof(double));
```

Comment: You are  roughly allocating about 16MB here. Should be no problem on an average pc. What exactly fails?

Comment: As a general rule, when you begin suspecting things like fragmentation, runtime library functions, or the operating system, immediately discard those suspicions and look for the bug in your code.

Comment: If the posted code were to be checking (!=NULL) the returned value from a call to `malloc()` and when it fails, then call `perror()` with an appropriate error message, then the OP would know what actually happened.   Also, in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer, Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: *part of malloc() code*,   Does this mean there is even more calls to `malloc()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably corrupt your heap here:

```
for(i=0;i<=Size;i++)
    u[i] = (double*)malloc(Size*sizeof(double));
```

You assign 1001 pointers, but only have 1000 allocated.
Correct version:

```
for(i=0;i<Size;i++)
    u[i] = (double*)malloc(Size*sizeof(double));
```

Same for the second loop.

Comment: It was such a stupid mistake. It's working fine now on pc. As it was running fine on server, I thought there was nothing wrong in the code.

Comment: @BlackHeart Yes, undefined behaviour is ugly, it may seem to work at one moment and then fail in the other.

Answer (score 4):

Read *carefully* the [documentation of `malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc). It *can* fail, and when it does fail, `malloc` returns `NULL` (and the failure reason is given by [`errno`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/errno) which you often display using [`perror`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/perror)).

So you should test against failure of `malloc`. The typical code is at least:

```
u = (double**)malloc(Size*sizeof(double*));
if (u==NULL) { perror ("malloc u"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

and likewise for your `rho_u` and every `rho_u[i]`

Some operating systems may provide [memory overcomitment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment). It is a feature I dislike.

Consider initializing *every* memory zone entirely. And using memory outside of a valid memory zone (or a valid address) is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (and your program have one, noticed by [Ctx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53905274/841108)). Be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46526702/841108).

I also recommend using [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/). It is a very handy tool to hunt memory related bugs, and could have detected yours.

Comment: All good advice but it's a simple buffer overrun bug as shown in Ctx's answer.

Comment: Sure, @CareyGregory, but by following this advice the OP could have been confident in rejecting their initial premise that `malloc` was failing.  They might then have studied their logic a little more carefully and found the real issue for themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Observation :

- Avoid typecasting  `malloc()`, Read [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
- Check the return value of `malloc()` & do proper error handling.
- Change loop condition from `i<=Size` to `i<Size` as it cause buffer overrun since earlier memory was allocated only for `Size` rows not `size+1` rows.

Try this version :

```
int Size = 1000;
double **u = malloc(Size * sizeof(*u)); /* typecasting is not needed */
if(u == NULL) {
   /* @TODO error handling */
}
for(i=0;i<Size;i++) { /* loop should rotate only 1000 times not 1001 times */
    u[i] = malloc(Size * sizeof(**u));
    if(u[i] == NULL) {
         /* @TODO error handling */
    }
}
```

Similarly for `rho_u` and `rho`.

Comment: The answer from "Ron Burk" in your linked question has many valid points too, it is "primarily opinion based" if you choose the pro's or the con's of casting the result of malloc to have more weight.