# C++ compilation takes forever

Tags: c++

I compiled the following short C++ code below with gcc compiler on Windows

```
#include <iostream>

#define MAXN 1000000009

using namespace std;

bool prime[MAXN] = {true};

int main()
{
    for (int p = 2; p * p <= MAXN; ++p)
        if (prime[p])
        {
            cout << p << "\n";

            for (int i = p * p; i <= MAXN; i += p)
                prime[i] = false;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

The code above prints prime numbers less than 1e9 with Sieve of Eratosthenes and doesn't have any errors,
but I noticed that the compilation takes even longer time than compilation of other of my C++ programs,
it took about few minutes to finish with no error messages.
To verify, I got the same result when I compiled again.
Even weirder, after the compilation, the code did not print anything and returned an exit code of 0.
I did not understand what's happening.
What caused this strange behaviour?

Comment: Your program has undefined behaviour. There is no element with the index of `MAXN` in the `prime` array.

Comment: `bool prime[MAXN] = {true};` will not set all of the elements to true. Also probably the source of the slow compiles. That's a lot of values to have to set. Check the size of the output file. It could be massive.

Comment: Well, your program flat out causes clang to crash, even with the UB removed (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c36771879c940c32). That `1000000009` seems to be the culprit, I'm not sure how though.

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). BTW don't confuse "compilation" with "complication". At last, the *compilation* of your program is quick, it is its *execution* which can take a lot of time.

Comment: Just checked. GCC 7.2 produces an output file of about a 1 GB in size. Almost certainly why it take so long to compile.

Comment: Notice that your `MAXN` is probably much too big. Read more about [prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) and [primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test). To find all primes less than 1e10 you only need an array of size 1e5

Comment: @StoryTeller Clang doesn't crash on my machine. Perhaps coliru limits memory.

Comment: On my Linux desktop the compilation of the above program (with GCC 8, using `g++ p.cc -o p.bin`) takes 8 seconds. That is *certainly not forever*. Of course, the program is crappy.

Comment: Consider not initializing `prime`. It's a global so it will be automatically set to false. Then invert the program logic so the program treats false as a prime. Comment the smurf out of this bit of insanity to explain why you're doing this. It should speed up the build time enormously.

Comment: Upgrading the compiler is a better option, to be sure.

Comment: @user4581301: no need to upgrade the compiler, as long as it is C++11 compliantr

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, it is not a *complication* (your program is not stellar, but simple) but a [*compilation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler).

On my Linux desktop (with an i5-4690s and [GCC 8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/) under Debian/Sid) the compilation with `g++ p.cc -o p.bin` of your less than optimal code takes about 8.2 seconds (certainly not forever).

Why does it take that much? Because you have an *initialized* but huge global variable (your `prime` array of booleans). So the compiler has to generate a huge binary executable (of about a gigabyte, most of it being the [`.data` segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment)).

If you don't initialize that global statically, but only inside your `main` function, by having

```
bool prime[MAXN];
int main() {
  prime[2] = true;
```

the generated executable becomes tiny -about 17Kbytes- (because now `prime` sits in the [`.bss` segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss)) and the compilation time is about 0.45 seconds.

If you wanted to initialize *all* the elements in `prime` you should use a `for` loop (or perhaps some [`std::memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset), when initializing a range of elements to the same value).

You should **think more *before* coding**. Read about [prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) and [primality tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test). You don't need such a big `prime`  array because you are looping about `√ MAXN` times (which is the maximal index you need), i.e. 31623 times. So you could have declared `bool prime[32000];` only (and change your program to only use elements in that range).

In practice, when you need a lot of memory, you'll better use [heap memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#HEAP).

If coding in C++, take advantage of its standard [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Of course, read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

BTW, your program is very inefficient. It takes about 10 seconds to run (as `p.bin > /tmp/p.out` with redirection to `/tmp/p.out` which gets 3401 lines). For comparison, the BSD `primes` program (in `/usr/games/primes` on my Debian), when run as `primes 2 31608 > /tmp/pp.out`, takes less than 2 milliseconds to produce *exactly* the same output file, so runs nearly 5000 times faster than yours.

As commented by [n.m.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m) your original program has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (you should be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46526702/841108)), because the `primes[MAXN]` element does not exist (you have a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)) but you are wrongly using it. So replace the inner `<= MAXN` with `< MAXN` or declare `bool prime[MAXN+1];`