# Segmentation Fault after using getline

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, getline

I'm learning C on Linux, and I did a small game in terminal. Everything was functioning until added a feature to ask for the nickname of the player at the beginning.

When I launch the program and then enter it, I'm getting an
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Here is a minimal error reproduction:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main (void) {
  bool condition = true;
  char *buffer;
  char *pseudo;
  size_t characters;
  size_t bufsize = 32;

  characters = getline(&buffer, &bufsize, stdin);
  pseudo = buffer; // make pseudo points to input obtained  
  // after this I have Segmentation fault (core dumped)
      
  while (condition == true) {
    // do something with pseudo
  }
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: None of your pointers are initialized to point at valid memory

Comment: @UnholySheep ... or `NULL` or `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `buffer`. And you'll better end your [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) format control string with `\n`  or else call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) before any input (since [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) is buffered).

An uninitialized pointer contains garbage. Using it is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46526702/841108) !

So my suggestion is to code

```
size_t bufsiz = 64;
char *buffer = malloc(bufsiz);
if (!buffer) { perror("malloc buffer"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

and later

```
printf("Salut ! Quel est ton nom ?\n");
characters = getline(&buffer,&bufsize,stdin);
```

Next time enable all warnings and debug info when compiling, so compile your code [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/). You would have got some warnings.

Of course, read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [*debugging with GDB*](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

On Linux, in your particular case, you could be interested in using [readline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html) instead of [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html).

Don't forget to read the documentation of every function that you are using (e.g. [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c), if it is a standard C one).

Comment: Thank you It worked! but if my buffer wasn't poiting any memory , why does it did work with all my program and never had this error ?

Comment: Follow all the links I am giving in my answer

Comment: Thank you very much ! Have a great day !

Answer (score 4):

[`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) can be used in two *different* ways:

1. Read into a buffer provided by the caller.
2. Allocate memory when reading.

To use 1. initialise the pointer passed to point to valid memory and pass as well the size of the latter.

```
#define INITIAL_SIZE (42)

int main(void)
{  
  char * buffer = malloc(INITIAL_SIZE * sizeof *buffer);
  size_t bufsize = INITIAL_SIZE;
  ssize_t characters = getline(&buffer, &bufsize, stdin);
  if (-1 == characters)
  {
     /* handle error. */
  }
  else
  {
     /* use buffer */
  }

  free(buffer); /* Free buffer. */
}
```

To use 2. initialise the pointer passed to `NULL` and pass `0` as size.

```
int main(void)
{
  char * buffer = NULL;
  size_t bufsize = 0;
  ssize_t characters = getline(&buffer, &bufsize, stdin);
  if (-1 == characters)
  {
     /* handle error. */
  }
  else
  {
     /* use buffer */
  }

  free(buffer); /* Free buffer. */
}
```

Note: `getline()` returns `ssize_t` *not* `size_t`.

Comment: Outsh! @NominalAnimal Fixed! Thx! :}

Answer (score 1):

'buffer' variable is pointing to some garbage memory address. You need to allocate necessary memory first, using 'malloc' function or make 'buffer' a static array, instead of pointer.

Comment: "*You need to allocate [...] memory first*" not necessarily. Please see my answer of an alternative to use `getline()`.

Answer (score 0):

[`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) is a [POSIX.1 function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html), which reads lines into dynamically allocated buffers, allowing lines of any length (limited only by the amount of available memory).  It returns the number of characters read, or -1 if there is no more input, or an error occurred.

Here is one example use pattern:

```
    char   *line = NULL;
    size_t  size = 0;
    ssize_t len;

    while (1) {

        len = getline(&line, &size, stdin);
        if (len < 1)
            break;

        /* Do something with the input line */

    }
```

At any point, you can release the dynamically allocated buffer using

```
    free(line);
    line = NULL;
    size = 0;
```

The reason you want to clear the pointer to NULL and size to zero is that that way, you do not accidentally try to access the already freed memory, but you can call `getline(&line, &size, handle)` to read more lines as the call will simply recognize it does not have a buffer, and will allocate a new one.

---

You can manipulate the dynamic data in any way you wish, if you are careful. For example:

```
while (1) {
    char   *line = NULL;
    size_t  size = 0;
    ssize_t len;

    len = getline(&line, &size, stdin);
    if (len < 1) {
        free(line);
        break;
    }

    /* Do something with the contents of the line */

    free(line);
}
```

will work, but it will be quite slow, because the C library will do at least one `malloc()` call for every line read, and possibly additional `realloc()` calls, depending on the line length.

The reason `getline()` is written as it is, is that it allows reusing the same buffer for any number of lines.  If you read files sequentially, you can reuse the same buffer.  Let's look at a more complex example:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned long  linenum;
    char          *line = NULL, *in, *out, *end;
    size_t         size = 0, n;
    ssize_t        len;
    FILE          *src;
    int            arg;

    if (!setlocale(LC_ALL, ""))
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Your C library does not support your current locale.\n");

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s FILENAME [ FILENAME ... ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {

        src = fopen(argv[arg], "r");
        if (!src) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[arg], strerror(errno));
            free(line);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        linenum = 0;

        while (1) {

            len = getline(&line, &size, src);
            if (len < 1)
                break;

            linenum++;

            /* First character in the line read: */
            in = line;
            out = line;

            /* Pointer to the end-of-string character on the line: */
            end = line + len;

            /* Skip all leading whitespace characters. */
            while (in < end && isspace((unsigned char)(*in)))
                in++;

            /* Character copy loop. */
            while (in < end)
                if (isspace((unsigned char)(*in))) {
                    /* Replace consecutive whitespace characters with spaces. */
                    *(out++) = ' ';
                    do {
                        in++;
                    } while (in < end && isspace((unsigned char)(*in)));
                } else {
                    /* Copy all other characters as-is. */
                    *(out++) = *(in++);
                }

            /* There may be a single space before out. Backtrack it, if so. */
            if (out > line && out[-1] == ' ')
                out--;

            /* Mark the end of the string at out. */
            *out = '\0';

            /* Calculate the new length, just for output purposes. */
            n = (size_t)(out - line);

            /* Print the line. */
            printf("%s: Line %lu: '%s' (%zu of %zd characters)\n",
                   argv[arg], linenum, line, n, len);

        }
        if (!feof(src) || ferror(src)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Read error.\n", argv[arg]);
            fclose(src);
            free(line);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (fclose(src)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Error closing file: %s.\n",
                            argv[arg], strerror(errno));
            free(line);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    free(line);
    line = NULL;
    size = 0;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If we save the above as say *example.c*, and compile it using e.g. `gcc -Wall -O2 example.c -o example`, and run the program supplying it with the names of text files as parameters, for example `./example example.c`, it will output something like

```
example.c: Line 1: '#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L' (31 of 33 characters)
example.c: Line 2: '#include <stdlib.h>' (19 of 20 characters)
example.c: Line 3: '#include <locale.h>' (19 of 20 characters)
example.c: Line 4: '#include <string.h>' (19 of 20 characters)
example.c: Line 5: '#include <stdio.h>' (18 of 19 characters)
example.c: Line 6: '#include <ctype.h>' (18 of 19 characters)
example.c: Line 7: '#include <errno.h>' (18 of 19 characters)
example.c: Line 8: '' (0 of 1 characters)
example.c: Line 9: 'int main(int argc, char *argv[])' (32 of 33 characters)
```

What the program does, is simply read each specified file line by line, remove any leading and trailing whitespace on each line, and combine all consecutive whitespace into a single space. The smaller character count is the number of characters left (and shown), the larger number is the original number of chars read from the file.

Additional notes on the example program, if it happens to interest you

- The `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` call tells your C library to use the users locale (usually defined in the `LANG` or `LC_ALL` environment variables). This program uses only the character type definitions for the character set used by the current locale (to determine which codes are "whitespace"), so this could also be limited to that, via `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")`.  The call will return NULL if the current locale is not supported by the C library.  Usually that is because of an error in the user configuration, so it is useful to have the program warn then.
- The `isspace()` (and all other `is*()` functions defined in `<ctype.h>`) take an unsigned character code (or EOF).  Because `char` type can be signed or unsigned, we explicitly cast the character to `(unsigned char)` before supplying to the function.  Consider this silly historical baggage that we just have to deal with this way.
- Because `line` points to the beginning of the dynamically allocated memory buffer, we must not modify it (except via `realloc()`, or `free()` and then set to `NULL`).  If we do modify it, any subsequent `getline()` or `free()` call using that pointer will likely freak out, and crash the program, since they really need the pointer to point to the beginning of the buffer, not just somewhere inside it.
- I like using pointers (`char *in, *out, *end`) instead of indexes.  Here, `in` starts at `line`, and goes up to but not including `line+len`, which is where `getline()` put the end-of-string nul `\0` to indicate the end of the line.  That's why I also often use a pointer named `end` to point to that.  The `out` starts at `line` also, but only increases when characters are kept in a line.

  If you think about a row of lettered tiles, like in scrabble, `out` points to the next position you'll put a kept tile, and `in` points to the next tile you get.
- When `getline()` or `getdelim()` returns a zero or a negative value (or `fgets()` returns NULL), it means that either there was no more data to read, or the operation failed for some other reason.
- After the loop, `(!feof(src) || ferror(src))` checks if the input stream was read completely without errors. Well, rather, the inverse: the expression is true only if an error occurred, or the entire file was not read.

  If I had written data to some file, say `FILE *dst`, I typically precede this test with `if (fflush(dst))` test. It is true if there is an error writing the last of the data buffered by the C library to the file.
- The `fclose(src)` closes the file.  I personally prefer to verify its return value, because even though *currently* it can only fail in very specific circumstances, I as an user would definitely prefer to know if the OS had issues writing my data!  The test costs basically nothing, but may be crucial for the user.  I do not want any programs to "forget" telling me there was a problem, when working on my data; my data is important to me.

  - `free(NULL)` is safe, and does nothing.  (Also, `realloc(NULL, size)` is equivalent to `malloc(size)`, so if you initialize a pointer to NULL, you don't need an initial malloc, you can just `realloc()` it always to the size you need.)

I suggest you play with the above code. You can even run it under ltrace (`ltrace ./example example.c`) to see which standard C library calls are actually performed, and their results; or under strace (`strace ./example example.c`) to see the syscalls (from the process to the OS kernel proper).

As an example, you could add say

```
        if (linenum == 7) {
            /* We skip line 7, and even destroy it! Muahhahah! */
            free(line);
            line = NULL;
            size = 0;
            continue;
        }
```

just after the `linenum++` line, to see what happens to the seventh lines of the text files.  (They're skipped, and even if the buffer is released, nothing bad happens (because `continue` starts the next iteration of the while loop body), as the next `getline()` will just dynamically allocate a new line.

If you decide you want to keep a copy of part of the line, just calculate the length you need adding one for the end-of-string nul (`\0`), allocate that many chars for the duplicate (`sizeof (char) == 1` in C, always; so malloc() et al. take the number of chars to allocate for, really), `memcpy()` the data, and add the terminating nul. For example,

```
char *sdup(const char *const source, const size_t  length)
{
    char *s;

    s = malloc(length + 1);
    if (!s) {
        /* Either return NULL, or: */
        fprintf(stderr, "sdup(): Not enough memory for %zu chars.\n", length + 1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (length > 0)
        memcpy(s, source, length);

    s[length] = '\0';
    return s;
}
```

If you want the full string (up to end of string nul), you can use the POSIX.1-2008 [`strdup()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) instead.