# Declaring function on another .c file makes float multiplication always be 0

Tags: c, floating-point

If I define the function in the main, everything works fine. But if I define the function in another c file, this weir float multiplication problem happens: it gives 0 always.

**example1/main.c:**

```
int multiply_by_2(float scalar) {
    printf("result: %f\n", scalar*2);
}

int main()
{
    multiply_by_2(3);
}
```

**example1/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.0)

project(example C)

add_executable(example main.c)
```

Output:

```
result: 6.000000
```

**example2/main.c:**

```
 int main()
    {
        multiply_by_2(3);
    }
```

**example2/a.c:**

```
int multiply_by_2(float scalar) {
    printf("result: %f\n", scalar*2);
}
```

**example2/CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.0)

project(example C)

add_executable(example main.c a.c)
```

Output:

```
result: 0.000000
```

Comment: You don't need `cmake` for such a simple example

Comment: Clearly this doesn't compile, or at least shouldn't. `printf()` isn't declared in `a.c`, and `multiply_by_2()` isn't declared in `main.c`... show the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int multiply_by_2(float scalar) {
   printf("result: %f\n", scalar*2);
}
```

you have an `int` returning function which does not `return` any integer. This triggers [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (once you call that `multiply_by_2` function elsewhere). Be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46526702/841108), very bad things could happen (even *outside* of that `multiply_by_2` function or outside of its caller).

Next time, compile with all warnings and debug info, so [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve your code to get no warnings.

Read also [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

If you use [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) numbers, be very cautious. They are difficult to understand and behave counter-intuitively (e.g. addition is not associative). Read http://floating-point-gui.de/ first.

If you have *several* [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) (e.g. source files such as `a.c` and `main.c`) you should in practice at least have some common [header file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive) and `#include` it in every `*.c` file. At a first approximation, your header file should declare all your  [global] types and functions. And you'll need to configure your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (e.g. write your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile)) to take into account such [dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)): your header file should somehow be mentioned.

Read much more about C programming. See also some [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) site. Read the documentation of every function you are using (e.g. of [printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf))

You'll learn a lot by studying the source code of *existing* small [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) programs (e.g. on [github](https://github.com/), [gitlab](https://gitlab.org/), in a Linux distribution, etc).

Comment: _you have an int returning function which does not return any integer. This is undefined behavior._ No, this is not undefined behavior. The behavior is undefined when the value of the function call is used by the caller in this case. The code shown in example2 nowhere uses the value of `multiply_by_2()` function call.

Comment: @H.S.: Huh. Learn something new every day. [N1570, 5.9.1 Function definitions, item #12](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=175): "If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @ShadowRanger Of course and that what I wrote in my comment - _The behavior is undefined when the value of the function call is used by the caller in this case._ In this sentence by "_in this case_", I am referring the case where the function is suppose to return some value but the return statement is missing.

Comment: @H.S.: Yeah, I was thanking you for pointing that out and providing the associated reference. I was surprised, and looked it up for myself; figured I'd save others the effort. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I should add a declaration of the functions in main.c, even though my compiler wouldn't warne me about it. With the declarations, all bugs are gone

Comment: I suspect turning up your warning level would get a warning output. Undeclared functions are kind of basic.

Comment: Actually, you should have some common header file and include it everywhere. Copy & pasting the same declaration in *several* files is not scalable and should be avoided (unless perhaps your C source files are generated from something else; then the *generator* could duplicate declarations)